# Python: What's wrong with this Python Code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# Define a procedure, median, that takes three
# numbers as its inputs, and returns the median
# of the three numbers.

# Make sure your procedure has a return statement.

def bigger(b,c):
    if b > c:
        return b
    else:
        return c
# if b is returned, then b >c
# if c is returned, then c > b 

def biggest(a,b,c):
    return bigger(a,bigger(b,c))


def median(a,b,c):
    if biggest(a,b,c) == c and bigger(a,b) ==a:
        # c > b and c > a 
        # a > b 
        return a
    elif biggest(a,b,c) == c and bigger(a,b)==b:
        # 
        return b
    else:
        return c 


print(median(1,2,3))
#>>> 2    (correct)

print(median(9,3,6))
#>>> 6    (correct)

print(median(7,8,7))
#>>> 7    (correct)

print(median(3,2,1)
#>>> 1    (incorrect)
```

It works perfectly fine when I run it with those three prints above, but when trying different prints the output is incorrect. For example when I tried print median(3,2,1)
the output was 1 which is an incorrect answer. What's the problem with this code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Comment: Why? I'm trying to delete it, but I can't.

Comment: You can't. It has up voted answers. Also: that's not how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: So you mean, once it's there, it's there forever?

Comment: Yup. One of the goals of Stack Overflow is to provide programming knowledge. If we were to delete every answered question, there'd be no programming knowledge to provide.

Comment: This question got `-2` so people don't find it helpful.

Comment: But the answer got three upvotes; that means that people found the answer useful. The reason your question was downvoted was because you essentially posted code and said "fix it".  People tend to downvote questions that are well written or researched. In your case, you could have debugged your code by putting print statements after every line, and that would have told you what the code was doing.  If you're going to post homework, make sure you've done everything you can: You've researched the problem, debugged your code, and come with a well written question.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You're awesome. Thanks for answering my intellectually low questions, and I am sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `c` isn't the biggest, you always return `c`. That includes when it's the smallest.

To fix it? Well, I'd just do

```
return sorted([a, b, c])[1]
```

but since this looks like homework, that answer probably relies too much on the library and too little on your own critical thinking. Instead, what if you found the biggest input, then returned the bigger of the other two?

Comment: Thank you very much, pardon me, because I am a beginner and have little experience with Python. This is homework, and I am trying to write the correct code, and not cheat. Since I know the problem is with c, now I will fix it, but I won't use the "return sorted.." because it's kinda of cheating. Again thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I know this is your homework but I couldn't resist. This is one method that does not use sorting (and it works I believe).

```
def median(a, b, c):

    if (a >= b and b >= c) or (c >= b and b >= a):
        return b
    elif (a >= c and c >= b) or (b >= c and c >= a):
        return c
    else:
        return a
```